# Convert IndexedSeq to Array

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a 2D Array, say a 3x3 Matrix, and want to multiply all elements with a given value. This is what I have so far:

```
val m = Array(
  Array(1,2,3),
  Array(4,5,6),
  Array(7,8,9)
)

val value = 3

for ( i <- m.indices) yield m(i).map(x => x*value)

//Result:
//IndexedSeq[Array[Int]] = Vector(Array(3, 6, 9), Array(12, 15, 18), Array(21, 24, 27))
```

Problem is I have an `IndexedSeq[Array[Int]]` now but I need this to be an `Array[Array[Int]]` just like `val m`.

I know that for example `for (i <- Array(1, 2, 3)) yield i` results in an `Array[Int]` but I can't figure out how to put this all together.

Just appending `.toArray` doesn't work also

Comment: Why doy ou need `Array`? what does it mean `toArray` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create new `Array` instances (copy):

```
  val m = Array(
    Array(1,2,3),
    Array(4,5,6),
    Array(7,8,9)
  )
  val value = 3
  val newM = m.map{ array => array.map{x => x * value}}
```

Or, if you want to modify the original arrays "in-place":

```
  val m = Array(
    Array(1,2,3),
    Array(4,5,6),
    Array(7,8,9)
  )
  val value = 3  
  for (arr <- m; j <- arr.indices) {
    arr(j) *= value
  }
```